# Android (Samsung Galaxy Tab) limit domains (websites) that can be browsed - web filter

Tags: android, filter

Is it possible to limit websites (domains) that can be accessed from android tablet (in our case Samsung Galaxy Tab 2)? 
I found out a couple of "web filter" apps but they all do the same thing - block adult/illegal websites. In our case I want to block everything except for one website.

The purpose of this is to enable customers in our store to browse only the online catalog through the tablet (but would not be able to navigate to other pages).

Comment: If you have root, you can set up an iptables rule to drop any connection not to your servers. Alternatively, what I think most apps do, you can start a proxy server on the device itself and tell Android to use it.

Comment: Check out an app that I work on: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsi.kioware.client.mobile.app. The app basically locks down the tablet to let you only access our browser. You can white-list or black-list domains and pages. It also includes many more features. You'll find more information about us at http://www.kioware.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy was the way to go! Worked like a charm - proxy on a server, limiting hosts that can be accessed and defining proxy on android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would need special privileges to achieve this. Specifically you would need Samsung to sign your code. It's not an easy thing, so I would look for complete solutions, like [this one](http://fancyfon.com)

Disclaimer: I don't work for them, I just want to provide example solution, that I have used